# ¿Cómo puedo capturar solo la primera ocurrencia con Grep?

Tags: grep

Tengo un texto en el que me aparece una palabra o un texto varias veces. Lo que quiero hacerlo es capturarlo, pero solo una vez. No que me los capture todas las veces.

Ejemplo

```
msg=$( zmore  datos.zip | grep -o -P '(?<=message=).*(?=,end)')
```

Ese el código que utilizo pero me captura todos los textos .

Comment: Necesitamos más información. Por favor, añade un [mcve] para que veamos qué tienes exactamente y cuál quieres que sea la salida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` tiene una opción `-m`/`--max-count` para establecer un límite de capturas:

```
$ cat file.txt
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
baz
```

```
$ grep foo file.txt
foo
foo
foo
```

```
$ grep -m 1 foo file.txt
foo
```

Cabe mencionar que dicha opción no es reconocida por la [norma POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), pero está disponible en implementaciones como [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) (lo encontrarás en prácticamente cualquier distribución Linux).

Comment: gracias era justo lo que necesitaba -m